# How do I convert StreamReader to a string?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I altered my code so I could open a file as read only. Now I am having trouble using `File.WriteAllText` because my `FileStream` and `StreamReader` are not converted to a string.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\"
                     + @"Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax\ActivityLog\OutboxLOG.txt";
    string outputPath = @"C:\FAXLOG\OutboxLOG.txt";

    var fs = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                      FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);
    string content = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

    // string content = File.ReadAllText(inputPath, Encoding.Unicode);
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, content, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: `StreamReader` is not a `string`. Using the `File.ReadAllText` method you have commented out would get a `string`.

Comment: It looks like you are just copying the contents of a file to another directory.  Why not make a copy of the file directly into the output directory?

Comment: Hey, glad you was able to decypher my comment on your last post...do a `using` on your FileStream...also you need to try/catch anytime you're doing disk IO...as you have already seen, there are lots of potential problems.  Other than that, these StreamReader.ReadToEnd() answers are what you need.

Comment: @docmanhattan What it really looks like is a learning excercise. :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

use the ReadToEnd() method of StreamReader:

```
string content = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode).ReadToEnd();
```

It is, of course, important to close the StreamReader after access. Therefore, a `using` statement makes sense, as suggested by [keyboardP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606858/1106367) and others.

```
string content;
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `using` statement for streams.

Comment: and using Path.Combine(...) instead of string concatenation, I know. I removed the noise from my answer leaving only the line that changed

Comment: Because my answer has been accepted, I've extended it to include a using statement as in @keyboardP's answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
string content = String.Empty;

using(var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode))
{
     content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

File.WriteAllText(outputPath, content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: +1 for adding the using statement to dispose the StreamReader

Answer (score 4):

Use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` method.